# How many days user has been alive calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

I have a snipped of code that I wrote that calculates how long the user has been alive. But the problem is, the program goes to hell if the user doesn't enter a integer e.g January or something else. I need to know how to stop this.

```
int inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the year you were born: ");
inputYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Month you were born: ");
inputMonth = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the day you were born: ");
inputDay = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

DateTime myBrithdate = new DateTime(inputYear,inputMonth, inputDay);
TimeSpan myAge = DateTime.Now.Subtract(myBrithdate);
Console.WriteLine(myAge.TotalDays);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Int32.TryParse(string, out into) - returns boolean on success

Comment: Please, always be precise _how_ your program "goes to hell". What exactly happens? While this specific case is simple enough to see that you are probably experiencing an unhandled exception, the exact manner of failure may not be obvious in general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the user doesn't enter a integer e.g January or something else

You can use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method then..

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style
>   and culture-specific format to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A
>   return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Month you were born: ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
int month;
if(Int32.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out month))
{
   // Your string input is valid to convert integer.
   month = int.Parse(s);
}
else
{
   // Your string input is invalid to convert integer.
}
```

Also `TryParse` method doesn't throw any exception and that's why you don't need to use any *try-catch* block with it.

> This is far above my level, I have no idea what is going on here.

Ok. I try to explain a little bir more deep.

What you complain is the users input right? Beucase you said, you want to put `int` as an input. Not `string` like "January" or "May" etc..

When you read input with [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, it returns a `string` as a return type, not `int`. Doesn't matter user put as an input `3` or `January`, this method returns them as a `string` regardless what they are type is.

`3` and `January` are strings in this case. **But how we check these strings are actually convertable to an integer value?** This is the part of why we using `Int32.TryParse` method. This method checks these inputs are convertable to integers or not so we can use this integer in `DateTime` constructor as a real integer.

Comment: Sorry I am newbie and am not sure how to read this. What does the
    if(Int32.TryParse(s, out month))
    {

    }
do?

Comment: @WindowsProdigy7 Don't you read my answer? It says: _Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style and culture-specific format to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded._ It checks whatever your input is convertable to `Int32` or not. If your conversation is success, it returns `true`. If your conversations isn't success, it returns `false`.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a goog solution! Anyways, i would add a try and catch block if there is a userinteraction - just because the errorhandling is important!this really saves time!

Comment: This is far above my level, I have no idea what is going on here

Comment: So this takes the string s and sees if it can be turned into a int with no except. And it sees if it wants to be a int through the Numberstyles.Integer and no exception is the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. Then then what does out month do?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this too me. However I get the int.TryParse part (that is checks if the string can be converted to and integer. I don't get what the text behind it does the. `(s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out month))`

Comment: @WindowsProdigy7 `Int32.TryParse` checks string is convertable or not to integer (it doesn't converts, just checks it), `Int32.Parse` converts it to integer. `out` is a method parameter. Read [out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Comment: What about the '(s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture' what does that do?

Comment: @WindowsProdigy7 Converts the string representation of a number **in a specified style** and **culture-specific format** to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is  because you are using int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); - the int stands for integer. Well you could put a try catch block arround your code.

The original code would stand in the try block, because you want to try to run it- but if an error accours ( e.g. user types jan), the catch block handles the error and your program could go on without troubles.